# Chinese caligraphy character recognition (three characters only)

Tags: character-identification

I am curious what the sign in the following picture says.

[image]

I am at total loss when it comes to caligraphic recognition, so I thought I would ask this forum for help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The banner is written from right to left (Chinese format)

豐 = abundant

澤 = blessing (gift)

寺 = temple

豐澤寺/ 丰泽寺 [fēng zé sì]: Temple of Abundant Blessing (gift)

Comment: Thank you for the quick recognition! I can definitely see the resemblance, but would have never figured it out myself.